# Scraping https returns an error on Mac but works on Windows

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to scrape table from the webpage into R on Mac:

```
library("rvest")
url <- "https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki_spolek_full"
gpw <- url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//table') %>%
html_table(fill = TRUE)
gpw



  Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer
  Error: object 'gpw' not found
```

When I am downloading table from this website in RStudio on Windows or via excel (Data tab -> Get External Data -> From Web) it works.

**EDIT:** 
I have problem with accessing this specific webpage. It seems like there is no connection at all.
When I try same code on different webpage it works.
for example:

```
url <- "https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapa"
Map <- url %>%
  read_html()
Map
{xml_document}
<html class="client-nojs" lang="pl" dir="ltr">
[1] <head>\n  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>\n  <title>Mapa – Wikipedia, wolna encyklopedia</title>\n  <s ...
[2] <body class="mediawiki ltr sitedir-ltr mw-hide-empty-elt ns-0 ns-subject page-Mapa rootpage-Ma ...
```

I was looking for similar cases but there was no answers for R (only some for php curl).

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working, but if you want a clean table, you will have to carry out some cleaning:

```
library("rvest")
url <- "https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki_spolek_full"
population <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//table') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

population
```

Comment: I does not work for me. I am still getting error `Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer` it looks like I can not connect to that website via R? `url <- "https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki_spolek_full"
population <- url %>%
  read_html()` returnes same error.

Comment: Why are you skipping  `html_nodes` and `html_table` commands?

Comment: To check is connection working. If it does population should be a list describing connected web page. For example this command `url <- "https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapa" Map <- url %>%
  read_html()
Map` works perfectly without any errors. I just simply can not connect to this specific webpage "https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki_spolek_full"  :(

Comment: Hmmm, I'm typing on my phone right now, so I cannot run the code. But it did work for me when I posted the script.

Comment: It looks like a website issue, not code-error. I cannot access the page...

Comment: I have read that sometimes when webtables are created by javascript it is much harder to scrape them, but I have no clue how to achive that.

Comment: I believe this is not the case. Just click on the link, you'll see 404 error.

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comment i have pasted not the full link, there is lack of "https://www". Correct one is https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki_spolek_full Sorry again, my bad.

Comment: Wow i have just find that you can not acces webpage by clicking the web url, but when you copy paste the web page adress into the web browser it works ... -  EDIT Stackoverflow is hiding "www" part link is OK.

Comment: No code does not work :( Code has correct url in it.

Comment: It worked for me. I extracted the table. Do you use R or RStudio?

Comment: Rstudio on Mac and you? I tried both with same effect :(

Comment: I tried both R and RStudio on Windows. Is your browser Chrome?

Comment: Nope, I am using safari. Does webbrowser have any effect on webscrapping?

Comment: Most probably. Can you try using Chrome?

Comment: I changed default browser for Chrome but it still does not work. I checked on windows and as you said it works - strange ...

Comment: Don't have a Mac, can't help.